# instantsearch.js with error in javascript console => RangeError: Invalid array length

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js

I have this error on javascript console for a long time.
It is related with instantsearch.js and the paginator.
Can anyone help?

```
range.ts:18 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Invalid array length
    at Ie (range.ts:18)
    at t.value (Paginator.js:31)
    at Object.render (connectPagination.js:147)
    at index.ts:481
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.render (index.ts:472)
    at InstantSearch.ts:510
    at defer.ts:26
```

This error appear when the page load and I initialize the search instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is what you need to do.

- [Algolia Documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/conditional-requests/vue/)
- [Code Sample](https://github.com/algolia/doc-code-samples/blob/master/vue-instantsearch/conditional-request/src/App.vue)

Finally. Inside your custom search client do this. Am using a sample computed property as my searchClient. Which will be cached thus not firing another request to Algolia.

```
search(requests) {
      if (requests.every(({ params }) => !params.query)) {
        // Here we have to do something else...
        // Since the query is empty i.e. ""

        return Promise.resolve({
          results: requests.map(() => ({
            // When an empty search is detected, a formatted response must be returned
            // with atleast below properties.
            // Otherwise;
            // RangeError is generated if all other fields aren't provided.
            hits: [],
            nbHits: 0,
            nbPages: 0,
            page: 0,
            facets: [],
            processingTimeMS: 0,
            hitsPerPage: 0,
            exhaustiveNbHits: false,
            query: "",
            params: "",
          })),
        });
      }

      // Else query using provided input
      return algoliaClient.search(requests);
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you Street Money. In fact, just need to "nbPages: 0,"